# AWS ELB returning its own private IP address?

Tags: amazon-elb

We've had a security scan done on some of our public IP's, for PCI compliance, and it was found that requests to one of our public IP's resulted in responses containing a private IP address.

The odd thing is, that the private IP address is in a range only used by our ELB's. Our application servers are in another private subnet.

Is it possible that the ELB itself could have been persuaded to return it's own private IP address?

If the issue was with our application servers, then I could correct it relatively easily, however I obviously have no way to resolve an issue with the ELB itself.

Does anyone know if, firstly, it's possible for an ELB to send a response with a private IP, and secondly, what to do to prevent it from doing this?

I haven't been able to reproduce the issue myself, but it must have happened, as the IP address is in the security report/

Comment: The most likely explanation is that your application is being persuaded to expose something about the incoming request or connection from the balancer.  There's no obvious mechanism in ELB or ALB... but unless the "security report" can tell you the mechanism that can be used to obtain the information, I'd respectfully suggest that your time is currently being wasted by whoever is providing you with this *incomplete* report.

Answer (score -1):

You can reproduce it with this command -

```
curl -v yourWebsite.com --http1.0 --header 'Accept:' --header 'Connection:' --header 'Host:'
```

From what I have read it is nothing to be concerned with since it is only exposing the load balancer.

Comment: I did this against one of my LBs and it did not return any internal IPs.